# Bilinear pairing

Tags: elliptic-curves, reference-request, pairings

I am working on Efficient Construction of Pairings which are being realized by Miller's algorithm. In this algorithm the basic steps are

1. point doubling and line function computation
2. point addition and line function computation, and last one is
3. exponentiation.

I know Point doubling and point addition steps because these are similar to standard ECC operations, but confused in line function computation. Why do we need this line function and how can I compute it?

Comment: Whichever source you are using to read about Miller's algorithm should also cover the line function... If not, you can of course always read the [original source](http://crypto.stanford.edu/miller/).